# Java ImageIcon on a Applet

Tags: java

I'm trying to set a ImageIcon next to a JLabel but

I cannot find what import the ImageIcon is.. I tried awt but it's nogo.

I'm gettign this error:

```
C:\Users\Dan\Documents\MainClass.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ImageIcon
location: class MainClass
    ImageIcon warnIcon = new ImageIcon("group.png");
    ^
C:\Users\Dan\Documents\MainClass.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ImageIcon
location: class MainClass
    ImageIcon warnIcon = new ImageIcon("group.png");
                             ^
2 errors
```

Tool completed with exit code 1

Code:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalIconFactory;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Label Text Pos");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

    Border border = LineBorder.createGrayLineBorder();
    //Icon warnIcon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("group.png"));
    ImageIcon warnIcon = new ImageIcon("group.png");
    //Image warnIcon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("group.png"));

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel(warnIcon);
    label1.setText("Left-Bottom");
    label1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.LEFT);
    label1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    label1.setBorder(border);
    frame.add(label1);

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(warnIcon);
    label2.setText("Right-TOP");
    label2.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.RIGHT);
    label2.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);
    label2.setBorder(border);
    frame.add(label2);

    JLabel label3 = new JLabel(warnIcon);
    label3.setText("Center-Center");
    label3.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    label3.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    label3.setBorder(border);
    frame.add(label3);

    JLabel label4 = new JLabel(warnIcon);
    label4.setText("Center-Bottom");
    label4.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    label4.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    label4.setBorder(border);
    frame.add(label4);

    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to try using the API to find out which package the class belongs to. You can't program if you don't have access to the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`javax.swing.ImageIcon`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html).